# Reading values .plist swift

Tags: ios, swift, random, property-list

I have a .plist in Swift. It is set up as follows

[image]

I have trouble finding information on how to read information from a .Plist.
I want to be able to randomly select one of the 845 Items in the EmojiList. Once I have that Item, then I want to have access to that Item's emoji string value and its description string value.

Programatically how would I go about accessing a random item inside the item list? And then having access to that specific item's properties?

Answer (score 0):

First load the plist in to an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary represents one emoji. Then generate a random index of the array, and pull out the dictionary at that index. Now use the dictionary to access the properties of the emoji.

```
var emojiArray: NSArray?
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("name-of-file", ofType: "plist"){
    emojiArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path)
}

if let array = emojiArray {
    let randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(array.count) // random number from 0 to array.count - 1
    let emojiDictionary = array[randomIndex]
    println("emoji value: \(emojiDictionary["emoji"]), emoji description: \(emojiDictionary["description"])"
}
```

Comment: if let emojiArray = emojiArray { ... }

Comment: @dash I am getting a error for "Use of unresolved identifier 'emoji' and 'description'

Comment: whoops those need quotes since the dictionary keys are strings, sorry about that! updated code.